# В приложении чёрный экран после перезагрузки программы

Tags: java, android

Вот как выглядит баг. Он проявляется  только на Android <6 выше 6 все ок.
В чем может быть причина?

YouTube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvNjXuIaIUo&feature=youtu.be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/activity2_Switch"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/sw_thumb" />


</LinearLayout>
```

...

```
ublic class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Vibrator Vibro;
    private SwitchCompat myswitch;
    public boolean Switch;


    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        ed.putBoolean("switchState", myswitch.isChecked());
        ed.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
        switch (currentNightMode) {
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
                // ночная тема не активна, используется светлая тема
                Switch=false;

                break;
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
                // ночная тема активна, и она используется
                Switch=true;

                break;
        }

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean switchState = prefs.getBoolean("switchState", Switch);
        myswitch.setChecked(switchState);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
        if (currentNightMode ==UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            setTheme(R.style.Home_Dark);
        }
        else setTheme(R.style.Home);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        if (currentNightMode ==UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {

            View someView = findViewById(R.id.view2);
            View root = someView.getRootView();
            root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_dark));       //фон




        }
        else
        {
            View someView = findViewById(R.id.view2);
            View root = someView.getRootView();
            root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));      //фон

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);                          //лого



        }


        myswitch=(SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        if (currentNightMode ==UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            myswitch.setChecked(true);
        }
        myswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    recreate();

                }
                else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    recreate();
                }
            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.exit)
                .setMessage(R.string.exit_yes)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Main2Activity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }




}
```

...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dima113xxx.coin_calculator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 70
        versionName "4.4.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled  true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Не надо в каждом вопросе в заголовке писать Java Android Studio. Вам каждый раз это удаляют, неужели до сих пор не дошло??? И метку Андроид Студио тоже не надо ставить, если вопрос не о самой этой программе.

Comment: В `onResume()` вызов `myswitch.setChecked(switchState);` порождает рекурсию. После этого вызова срабатывает слушатель переключателя, который перезапускает активность (`recreate()`), она доходит до `onResume()` и всё по-новой.

Answer (score 0):

Начал разбираться  и нашел

в  onResume()

```
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean switchState = prefs.getBoolean("switchState", Switch);
        myswitch.setChecked(switchState);
```

Без этого все работает - видимо оно циклиться и за этого и черный экран. (Вечно обновляется)

Но почему на андроиде выше 6 все ок ?????

Comment: Дополнение к вопросу нужно писать в самом вопросе - для этого под ним есть кнопка [`править`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1024220/edit).