# При перезапуске приложения - черный экран (подозрение на бесконечный цикл)

Tags: java, android

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Vibrator Vibro;
    private SwitchCompat myswitch;
    public boolean Switch;


    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        ed.putBoolean("switchState", myswitch.isChecked());
        ed.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
        switch (currentNightMode) {
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
                // ночная тема не активна, используется светлая тема
                Switch=false;

                break;
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
                // ночная тема активна, и она используется
                Switch=true;

                break;
        }

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean switchState = prefs.getBoolean("switchState", Switch);
        myswitch.setChecked(switchState);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
        if (currentNightMode ==UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            setTheme(R.style.Home_Dark);
        }
        else setTheme(R.style.Home);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        if (currentNightMode ==UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {

            View someView = findViewById(R.id.view2);
            View root = someView.getRootView();
            root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_dark));       //фон

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);                          //лого
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.nameless000_dark);

            TextView resText7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);                             //вывод
            resText7.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light));


        }
        else
        {
            View someView = findViewById(R.id.view2);
            View root = someView.getRootView();
            root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));      //фон

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);                          //лого
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.nameless000);

            TextView resText7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);                             //вывод
            resText7.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark));


        }


        myswitch=(SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        if (currentNightMode ==UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            myswitch.setChecked(true);
        }
        myswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    recreate();

                }
                else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    recreate();
                }
            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.exit)
                .setMessage(R.string.exit_yes)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Main2Activity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }


    public  void  onClick0(View view){

        Vibro = (Vibrator)this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        Vibro.vibrate(50);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    public  void  onClick1(View view){

        Vibro = (Vibrator)this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        Vibro.vibrate(50);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    public  void  onClick2(View view){

        Vibro = (Vibrator)this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        Vibro.vibrate(50);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main4Activity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    public  void  onClick3(View view){

        Vibro = (Vibrator)this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        Vibro.vibrate(50);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main5Activity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

}
```

Данный код хорошо работает начиная с api выше 23. Ниже  данного api,при перезапуске приложения - черный экран . Я подозреваю что это бесконечный цикл в данном месте кода.

```
 super.onResume();

        int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
        switch (currentNightMode) {
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
                // ночная тема не активна, используется светлая тема
                Switch=false;

                break;
            case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
                // ночная тема активна, и она используется
                Switch=true;

                break;
        }
```

Если убрать это место с кода, то хотя бы запускается но естественно без сохранения положения switch

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean switchState = prefs.getBoolean("switchState", Switch);
        myswitch.setChecked(switchState);
```

Логи

```
10-17 15:26:58.774 1396-1409/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{9fbce010 dima113xxx.coin_calculator/.Main2Activity}

    --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
10-17 15:26:59.074 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.074 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.104 2213-2213/com.android.launcher D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-17 15:26:59.124 2213-2213/com.android.launcher D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 2171K, 45% free 30173K/54087K, paused 1ms+4ms, total 20ms
10-17 15:26:59.134 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.134 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.154 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.154 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.174 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.174 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.214 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.214 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.244 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.244 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.274 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.274 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.314 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.314 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.344 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.344 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.374 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.374 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.414 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.414 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.444 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.444 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.474 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.474 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.514 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.514 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.544 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.544 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.574 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.574 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.604 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.604 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:26:59.644 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0xb7b8d5b8
10-17 15:26:59.644 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 1 attribute 1 vbo 1 allocedBufferSize 64 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 88
10-17 15:27:00.004 1526-1526/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb7b51400: ver 2 0
10-17 15:27:00.764 2213-2213/com.android.launcher D/OpenGLRenderer: GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x502
10-17 15:27:00.764 2213-2213/com.android.launcher E/OpenGLRenderer:   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Как быть , и что можно предпринять ?(И почему выше api 23 все хорошо. )  Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891511/how-to-avoid-activity-pause-timeout-for-activityrecord-error

Comment: я написал сохранение и загрузку (SharedPreferences) через таймер в 500мс и сработало (я даже 100 поставил ) больше нет черного экрана.Но почему в api >23 все ок ! И что это за ошибка такая.

Comment: [Дежавю...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1024220#comment1748261_1024220) В `onResume()` вызов `myswitch.setChecked(switchState);` порождает рекурсию. После этого вызова срабатывает слушатель переключателя, который перезапускает активность (`recreate()`), она доходит до `onResume()` и всё по-новой. Может записать в префы не успевает - `super.onPause();` перенесите в конец метода. Или надо колдовать со слушателем, чтобы не срабатывал на программное переключение

Comment: Я даже ставлю 1 мс  и все работает.

Comment: Не  super.onPause(); не super.onResume(); в конце метода ничего не дает . Только с таймером все работает.Может стоит оставить 1 мс?Главное чтобы не повторялось больше